# How to search for the second occurence of ' or " in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

String combinations:

```
str_search = adfa odf 'aso'
str_search = do o sfo o'sfsdf'
str_search = sdfosd'sf sd'
```

What i've done so far:

```
if( /\s*\S*["|']\s*\S*["|']$/.test(str_search) ){
alert('at the 2nd quote');
    //replace the string enclosed in quotes with !string!
}//if
```

The string combinations at the first block must go inside the condition at the 2nd block. Therefore the ff **should not enter** the condition in the 2nd block

```
str_search = adfa odf 'aso
str_search = do o sfo osfsdf'
str_search = sdfosd'sf sd's
```

Comment: "The condition must be true at the end of..." I'm afraid I have no idea what you are trying to tell us? What do you want to achieve with those inputs? Are the right-hand sides of those `=` actually wrapped in quotes (i.e., is `"adfa odf 'aso'"` the string?).

Comment: Your regex matches on strings that have at least one quote, but your example string only have apostrophes?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pdasA/)?

Comment: @jerry - Yes, but i need you need to include $, because it must go inside the cond if the last part of str_search is ' or " and the ' or " it seen is a second occurence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from your updates, it seems that you can use something a bit like this:

```
str = "adfa odf 'aso'";

if(/(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")$/.test(str)){
    res = str.replace(/(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")$/, "!string!");
    alert(res);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdasA/4/).

Comment: it must not go inside if str = "adfa odf 'aso'a";

Comment: i got it, your fiddle is not matching with the one posted here, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work to replace a string in quotes:

```
> "a 'asdf'".replace(/'[^']*'/, "replacement");
"a replacement"
```

In plain english: look for a quote, any number of non-quote characters and another quote and replace all of that with "replacement".