# Replacing all string enclosed with " or '

Tags: javascript, regex

text = `abc "def" g'i' jklm'no' p"qrs uv w"`

should become `abc !string! g !string! jklm!string! p !string!`

What i have so far:

```
if(/(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")/.test(text){
   text = text.replace(/(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")/, "!string!");
}
```

(Jerry's answer)

It only replace the first occurence of text enclosed with '' or "". This is actually related to my previous question but this is more complicated i think: [How to search for the second occurence of ' or " in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275971/how-to-search-for-the-second-occurence-of-or-in-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [g](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) modifier performs a global match

```
text = text.replace(/(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")/g, "!string!");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
str = "abc \"def\" g'i' jklm'no' p\"qrs uv w\"";
mystring = str.replace(/("|')+[a-z ]+("|')/g, '!sring!');
alert(mystring);
```

**output**:

```
abc !string! g !string! jklm!string! p !string!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the global parameter "g"

```
str.replace(/blue/g,"red");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var str = "abc \"def\" g'i' jklm'no' p\"qrs uv w\"";
var regexp = /("|')[a-z ]+("|')/g;
console.log(str.replace(regexp,'!string!'));
```

[image: Regexpr results]

Result: `abc !string! g!string! jklm!string! p!string!`